# Bitmap to DTMF Signal

Tags: bitmap, signals, dtmf

I want to know if it is possible to convert an bitmap image to an DTMF signal via software.
For example, to send an image via call, over a GSM network, without using any cellular data.

Comment: So you want some kind of data-over-dtmf? Nice :) Although even if such software exists already I would not expect great speed for it.

Answer (score 0):

Converting data to base 10 or 12 would be pretty easy, but that's going to be an extremely inefficient way of doing it.  Here are a couple of better alternatives:

- [Use an analog modem library](http://www.whence.com/minimodem/minimodem.1.html)
- [Send data as SMS](https://github.com/ColdSauce/CosmosBrowserAndroid)